# Pandas field transformation using something like a case statement

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to update a field in a DataFrame using the following logic. The field to be updated is `UnitOfAccount`. I want to be able to, if `issueYear < 2016`, then concat `SubUnit + '_prior2016' + prefix`, else `SubUnit + prefix`. What's the best way to achieve this?

Example data:

```
IssYr SubUnit Prefix Result 
2020  103     wh_l   103_wh_l 
2016  103     wh_1   103_Prior2016_wh_1
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some example data?

Comment: Example data

IssYr  SubUnit Prefix  Result
2020    103     wh_l    103_wh_l
2016 103     wh_1    103_Prior2016_wh_1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use a boolean mask:

```
mask = df['IssYr'] < 2016

df['Result'] = df['SubUnit'].astype(str) + '_' + df['prefix']

df.loc[mask, 'Result'] = (df['SubUnit'].astype(str) + 
                          '_prior2016_' + 
                          df['prefix'])
```

Comment: I'm new to Pandas, but if I'm reading that correctly won't that only update those records where the 'IssYr' < 2016

Comment: That's right, the third statement using `df.loc[mask, 'Result'] = ...` will only update rows where `mask == True`. This is intentional: the second statement (`df['Result'] = ...`) creates the column using the rule for when `df['IssYr'] >= 2016`, and the third statement then overwrites `df['Result']` in rows where `df['IssYr'] < 2016`. Have you tried this on your data?

Comment: I did, but I only saw the records where 'IssYr' < 2016 were updated, all others wer blank

Comment: That's weird. What is the result of just the first statement, `df['Result'] = df['SubUnit'].astype(str) + '_' + df['prefix']`?

Comment: I did it the following way  df[cohort] = df["IssYr"].where(df["IssYr"].astype(int) >= 2016, "prior2016") then df["UnitOfAccount"] = df["SubUnit"].astype(str) + "_" + df["Cohort"]

Comment: When you say you did it that way, do you mean that is what ended up working?

Comment: Yes, it gave me what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to hear it!